# Distribution of random variable $Y$ passed throught distributin function of $X$

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If 
\begin{align*}
F(x)=P[X \le x] 
\end{align*}
is continuous in $x$, show that $Y=F(X)$ is measurable and that $Y$ has uniform distribution 
\begin{align*}
P[Y \le y]=y, \, 0 \le y \le 1.
\end{align*}

Showing that $Y$ is measurable is easy. Since, the map is continuous therefore it is measurable. 
How to show that $Y$ has uniform distribution?
I was thinking something like this
\begin{align*}
P(Y \le y)=P(F(X) \le y)
\end{align*}
but how do I proceed next? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\Pr(F(X)\le y) = \Pr(X\le F^{-1}(y)) = F(F^{-1}(y))=y.
$$
That works if $F$ is invertible, since invertible CDFs are strictly increasing.